# vue - datatable - item-expanded - load from server

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the component datatable from Vuetify library. There is a problem on **item-expanded**, the code

```js
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="records"
  :options.sync="options"
  :server-items-length="totalRecords"
  :loading="loading"
  :search="search"
  disable-pagination
  :hide-default-footer="true"
  class="elevation-1"
  show-expand
@item-expanded="loadDetails">
<template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
    <td :colspan="headers.length">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id" data-visible="false">id</th>
                    <th data-field="league_id" >league_id</th>
                    <th data-field="Start" >Start</th>
                    <th data-field="End" >End</th>
                    <th data-field="Current" >Current</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="rec in item.details" :key="rec.id">
                <td>{{ rec.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ rec.league_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ rec.start }}</td>
                <td>{{ rec.end }}</td>
                <td>{{ rec.current }}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</template>
</v-data-table>

  loadDetails: function({item}) {
    
    if (item.details)
        return;

    this.ChildApiCall(item).then((data) => {
        item.details = data.response;
    })

//     var self = this;
// return new Promise(function (resolve) {
//     self.ChildApiCall(item).then((data) => {
//         item.details = data.response;
//         resolve(item);
//     })
//      });
},
  async ChildApiCall(item) {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("action", "GetRecordDetailsLeaguesJS");
      formData.append("recID", item.id);

      const items = await general.GetData("/api/03leagues.php", formData);
      return items;
    }
```

if I add to server call (03leagues.php) **1 second** delay on response, the row expanded but showing only the table **header** row. When collapse and expand again, showing the table as should be.

[image]